# Redirecting shell command outputs to another konsole shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am writing a shell script and I would like to write commands in the script but redirect the output to other konsole sessions. (using kde)

Answer (score 4):

First, look for the number that identifies the current tty session; lets consider the number as `X`:

```
| terminal 1               | terminal 2                |
 ------------------------------------------------------
| $ tty                    | $                         |
| /dev/pts/X               |                           |
```

Then, use the given number to write to the tty selected:

```
| terminal 1               | terminal 2                |
 ------------------------------------------------------
| $ tty                    | $ echo "foo" > /dev/pts/X |
| /dev/pts/X               |                           |
```

And it will produce:

```
| terminal 1               | terminal 2                |
 ------------------------------------------------------
| $ tty                    | $ echo "foo" > /dev/pts/X |
| /dev/pts/X               |                           |
| foo                      |                           |
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe the output to a log file which is tailed by other sessions.

In any other terminal:

```
touch foo && tail -f foo
```

In the "main" terminal:

```
script.sh > foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Print terminal output to file, rather than the terminal your currently in:

```
commands >>outputfile
```

In new terminal, use tail to show contents of outputfile and update it automatically as more text is added:

```
tail -f outputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Late but maybe better then never... :-)

```
mkfifo ~/MyOutput           # Create the FIFO (Special file) 

./MyScript.sh > ~/MyOutput  # In the terminal/console 1
cat ~/MyOutput              # In another tty/console
```

from `info coreutils 'mkfifo invocation'`:

> A "FIFO" is a special file type that permits independent processes
>   to communicate.  One process opens the FIFO file for writing, and
>   another for reading, after which data can flow as with the usual
>   anonymous pipe in shells or elsewhere.

Side notes:

- It's better to create the FIFO not in your home directory :-)
- You can have more than one `FIFO` for the same process (std out, std err).
- Untill you will not ask a dump from `FIFOs` it will hold all the output.
  As you will ask the first time, it will *flush out* all.
- You can redirect (or append) to another file `cat MyOutput >> NewRealFile`
- You can use `cat MyOutput` from another terminal too!
- **Warning**: If you ask to a 2 diffent programs (or instances) to redirect output to the same `FIFOs` the flux will be merged (no *a priori* way to distinguish from which programs that line comes from).
- **Warning**: If you ask 2 or more times (maybe from different terminals) it will give one line for each request splitting the output to the requester.
- It can have more complex uses: [How to properly launch a program and make possible to redirect its running output (stdout and stderr) at a later stage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129011/66388)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tty` command in each terminal to identify them:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/0

$ tty
/dev/pts/1
```

Assuming these TTYs, to redirect the first's stdout to the second, run this in the first terminal:

```
exec 1>/dev/pts/1
```

> Note: Now **every command output** will show on pts/1

To restore default behavior stdout of pts/0:

```
exec 1>/dev/pts/0
```

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqVQxehmfuo) for a demonstration.