# Pipe the xkcdpass Ouput as file to another script

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I have a script that needs a file as argument :

```
./myscript --file filename.txt
```

**xkcdpass** generates lists of passphrase as output .

How can I PIPE the output of **xkcdpass** , as a file, to myscript ??

Till now I tried this :

```
./myscript --file | xargs xkcdpass
```

... but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `xkcdpass` generate a list of passwords and you do not want to store in a file.
You can try to create a FIFO.

```
mkfifo ~/MyOutput 
xkcdpass > ~/MyOutput &   # & to execute it in the background
```

then

```
./myscript --file ~/MyOutput
```

from `info coreutils 'mkfifo invocation'`:

> A "FIFO" is a special file type that permits independent processes to communicate. One process opens the FIFO file for writing, and another for reading, after which data can flow as with the usual anonymous pipe in shells or elsewhere.

---

You should try also

```
xkcdpass | xargs -n 1  ./myscript --file
```

---

You can read more:

- [Redirecting shell command outputs to another konsole shell](https://superuser.com/questions/570212/redirecting-shell-command-outputs-to-another-konsole-shell/982512#982512)
- [How to properly launch a program and make possible to redirect its running output (stdout and stderr) at a later stage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129011/66388)

Answer (score 1):

"How can I PIPE the output of xkcdpass , as a file, to myscript ??"
With a [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

```
./myscript --file <(xkcdpass)
```